# Injecting a Spring bean that is from a dependency, but doesn't have @Bean annotation

Tags: spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection

My `Spring Boot` app has a new `Zoo` `@Service` class:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Service
public class Zoo{
    private final Cat cat;
```

I need to inject in the constructor a `Cat` class that I get from a legacy library that I import to the project via the pom:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>animals</artifactId>
    </dependency>

package com.example.animals
class Cat{..}
```

I can't change the code of the legacy `animals` package in order to add an annotation to the `Cat` class.

When I try to run the application I get this error:

> Parameter 0 of constructor in com.example.zoo required a bean of type 'com.example.animals.cat' that could not be found

Is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can solve this by creating a `@Configuration` class where you define a Spring Bean which represents an instance of a Cat, like in the following example.

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfiguration {

  @Bean
  public Cat cat() {
    return new Cat();
  }
}
```

Comment: Does the argument name specified in the constructor need to match the method name `cat` for this to work?

Comment: No, it is not a need.